# Codeigniter URL rewrite --- Something strange

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I just re-writed using htaccess ( with that I just removed the index.php part )

I just got a URL like this

```
http://localhost/mvc/movies/movie/3237-Movie-name-here
```

where 
mvc - this root folder
movies - controller
movie - view
3237- Query string for getting from DB ( pk)
Movie-name - for SEO URL

with this I can get the movie details with pk 3237

Now I just need to rewrite this url to ( using htaccess )

```
http://localhost/mvc/movie/3237-Movie-name-here
```

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uri routing ? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CODEIGNITER Routing. Described in here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

In your case `$route['mvc/movies/([:num)/(:any)'] = "mvc/movie/$1-$2";`

Comment: thanks for your reply .. I tried this ... but showing 404 error ... 
for eg I just wrote a sample to re-direct http://localhost/mvc/news to http://mvc/movies/movie ... here is the confg line .. please help 
$route['movies/movie/'] = "/news";

Comment: $route['movies/movie/(:any)'] = "movie/$1"; Try this
This will rewrite 
http://localhost/mvc/movies/movie/3237-Movie-name-here to 
http://localhost/mvc/movie/3237-Movie-name-here